# Batch file to copy files from multiple folders to a single folder, overriding if date is newer

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to be able to copy all files from various folders and combine them into a single folder using a Windows batch file. That is fairly easy to do for me. But if the file already exists on the destination, I would like it to only override the file if it's newer.

```
copy c:\pics\ to d:\
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code you show does not "copy all files from various folders and combine them". Post your code and we might then help you more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xcopy` for more options if the source dirs are 2-3-5 (write separate xcopy lines for each). If the dirs are too many, you can use archiver like WinRar (or its command line rar.exe) with @list option where are stored the source dirs. In the batch file call RAR 2 times - first to pack all source files to one archive, then to unrar them in single folder (with E option, not X). Finally, you delete the .rar file. See the extra options to skip older files, omit prompts, etc.